# HTML&CSS + Twitter Bootstrap: any form element to left and button to right (row section)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We need position `Phone`, `Name`, and `Firstname` to left and `button` to right. I try with `float-left` and `float-right`, is it OK for the first row but after is it more complexe.
For the second row, I try use a `row`+`col-1..` but `Phone`, `Name`, and `Firstname` not grouped with the `input`

```
  +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |  Title                                                              | button | |
  +------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |  Phone | input |    Name | input |    Firstname | input |           | button | |
  +------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |  Content table                                                                 |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: can you please add your code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)?

Example with **Bootstrap** [auto margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#auto-margins):

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <form class="form-inline w-100 d-flex">
    <div class="form-group mr-4">
      <label for="field-1"class="mr-2">Field #1</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="field-1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mr-4">
      <label for="field-1"class="mr-2">Field #2</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="field-2">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success ml-auto">Button</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

live example on https://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/5svek2xn/

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bootstrap's 'from-inline' with spacing utilities for Phone, Name and First name. For button use the 'ml-auto' for right align without using the 'float-left' or 'float-right'.